# How to get a xml file from iphone's email and use it in my app

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing, download

Suppose i want to open an xml file which i have in my email through my app. How should i go for this.
Thanks,

Comment: You wouldn't. There is no access to a users private data like their email contents.

Comment: Suppose there is a picture attached in a different format how would the user be able to see the content. We are making this application for the user itself and would not import this data anywhere. You can see this thing as we are maknig a pdf reader to allow user to read pdf they receive in their email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment you just posted.  I would do it this way:

Have the person send the email with a link to the file using a 3rd party service (create one?? Shouldn't be too hard considering what you want to do) and use a custom URL scheme to automatically launch your application, then load the file

If you don't know how to create a custom url scheme, just go [here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

Comment: How to create a thord party service?? and what do i need to make one

Comment: just create a website that is a simple php script to retrieve the file based on the url.  ex: myapp://55jJH3 will go to your url (which you will define in your iphone code) with 55jJH3 after the ?whatever= then will do a simple mysql query to get the file name, then it'll return the file

Comment: Can you provide me with some links that would help me create this.

Comment: laready have a website but the server doen't support php it supports JScript though.

Comment: then just have url be the file name and just return the file directly.

Comment: so you mean to say i should save the file on my webspace and name the file as the my url appended with the app name and get the file. But what about saving the file on my webspace.

Comment: if possible provide me with some example or some link