# Can we open Email account inside our app?

Tags: iphone, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to build an application through which i would have some control on the content of the mail like one should be able to parse the xml he/she just received attached in an Email.

How should i do it ?? Any idea??

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You asked this question already. What's wrong with the answer you received?

[How to get a xml file from iphone's email and use it in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730341/how-to-get-a-xml-file-from-iphones-email-and-use-it-in-my-app)

You can access email directly from an application other than Apple's Mail App. Follow the advice you got in your first question.